# Object values are not updating in template view

Tags: angular

When I'm subscribing the service after getting data my object values are not updating in the template view @angular

```
`` 
subscription: Subscription;
userDatafromDB: UserRead;
constructor(
    private _userinfo: UserdetailService
  ) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._userinfo.UserDetailsChanged$.subscribe(
      (data: UserRead) =>
        data != null
          ? (this.userDatafromDB = data)
          : (this.userDatafromDB = null)
    );
  }``
```

HTML :

```
``  <h2>EMAIL ::: {{ userDatafromDB.email }}</h2>``
```

Comment: Did you try to console log your `userDatafromDB` to check whether if it is coming correctly or not?

Comment: Why don't you use `async` pipe?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari: yeah my data is visible

Comment: @JosefKatič : yeah I will try

Comment: please try to console log your `data` and share the response with us.

Comment: Does the `Observable` really change?

Comment: `handleData(data) {
    this.userDatafromDB = data;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._userinfo.UserDetailsChanged$.subscribe(
      (data: UserRead) => this.handleData(data)
    );
  } `   :::: this worked for me.

Comment: That's the solution for your problem?

Comment: yeah, it worked for me. When the response is loaded my view is updating. new to the async pipe will try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return the entire statement on your subscribe(). Try changing your `ngOnInit` on your component.ts to this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this._userinfo.UserDetailsChanged$.subscribe(
    (data: UserRead) => {
      data != null
        ? (this.userDatafromDB = data)
        : (this.userDatafromDB = null)
   });
}
```

And on your component.ts, use the safe navigation operator on your `userDatafromDB` to guard it from errors resulting from null values.

```
<h2>EMAIL ::: {{ userDatafromDB?.email }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `async` pipe in this case. It would subscribe the same as you do and you don't have to handle subscription code.

*.component.ts

```
userDetails$: Observable<UserRead>;
constructor(private _userinfo: UserdetailService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetails$ = this._userinfo.UserDetailsChanged$;
}
```

*.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userDetails$ | async as userDetails">
   <h2>EMAIL ::: {{ userDetails.email }}</h2>
</ng-container>
```